# Shipping charge by country & product weight?

Tags: e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am using WP E-Commerce plugin.

In my e-commerce platform, there is two variable for product price.
Its based on location (ie. india, usa, canada (not by continent)), and weight also.

How can I achieve this, is there any plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be perfect for you: [Region Weight Shipping](http://getshopped.org/fpt-plugins/region-weight-shipping/)